# POSTGRES: Change Column Data Type from numeric(18, 2) to numeric(22, 6) on a BIG Table (8 billion plus rows)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, rdbms, alter-table

We have a very big **POSTGRES** table containing more than ***8 BILLION*** rows and growing at a very high rate (***30 million rows per day***).

Our Table is **Partitioned** on **date**. Each partition contains **6 months** data except the **first partition** which contains data for almost **18 months**.

> **Postgres version**: PostgreSQL 12.11

> **Database specs:** **db.r6g.16xlarge**   (vCPU:64, memory:512,
> EBSBandwidth(Mbps):19000)

**Table schema:**

```
create table table_1
(
    id       bigint default nextval('table_1_id_seq'::regclass) not null,
    user_id  integer                                            not null,
    amount   numeric(18, 2)                                     not null,
    date     timestamp                                          not null,
    column_1 varchar                                            not null,
    column_2 varchar,
    .
    .
    primary key (id, date)
) partition by RANGE (date);
```

This table also contains **multiple indexes** (including **partial indexes**)

```
create index index_1
    on table_1 (column_1);

create index index_2
    on table_1 (date, column_2, column_3);

create index index_3
    on table_1 (column_4);

create index index_4
    on table_1 (user_id, column_3);

create index index_5
    on table_1 (user_id asc, date desc)
    where (column_3 = ANY (ARRAY [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10]));

create index index_6
    on table_1 (user_id, column_2, column_3, column_5);
```

Initially we created **amount** column with **data type numeric(18, 2)**. Now we need to support **higher precision** upto 6. So we need to change our type to **numeric(22, 6)**.

Now running an **Alter command** like below one is taking a lot of time (**hours**):

> NOTE: we ran this command on the table without dropping any indexes

```
ALTER TABLE table_1 ALTER COLUMN amount type numeric(22, 6);
```

Few of the **different strategies** that we are exploring:

1. Drop all the **indexes**, **triggers** and **foreign keys** while the update runs and **recreate** them at the **end**.
2. **Create new table**:

   a. Create a new **partitioned** table with exact same **configuration**,

   b. **migrate** **data** from old to new table.

   c. **create all indexes** on new table.

   d. **remove** old table.

> NOTE: Our primary goal is to minimise the down time. If in doing so a
> **BIGGER DB instance** can help, we are open to explore that as well.

We want to explore if there are **any other strategies** to do this **task** OR in our **current strategies** what can we **do extra** or **different** to **minimise our down time**.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: One option to consider is creating a new table with the structure you want, copying the data into it and then doing a rename.  With the high transactional volume, all you have to account for once it's renamed is adding back the missing data from the original, which will be < 30 million.

Comment: can you elaborate, how the runtime changed? such tasks must be done during maintenance. where you should have implemented a strategies for long running processes. Maybe DBA is a  better place for such a question